# Send Selected Object to another Control in WPF/Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, events, wpfdatagrid, eventaggregator

I am working on a WPF Projet, in which I have a view with two usercontrols on it. This is basically a UserControl with a grid on it and another one with a edit panel to edit the selected object in the DataGrid. The edit panel control, consists of textboxes to edit properties of the selected object in the other control and a button to save. What I would like to do is to pass the selected object to the edit panel,that is each time a object is selected in the grid, the edit panel updates to select that same object. What is the best way to do this, please help?An example would be super :0)

Comment: You provide no code examples explaining clearly what you're asking, yet expect somebody to answer your question with some code example to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with this is using the MVVM pattern, where both of your user controls bind to the same ViewModel.

The grid can bind to your collection (List<>) of objects that you want to show, and it can also bind its SelectedRow/SelectedItem property to a corresponding property on the ViewModel called SelectedItem (or similar). This means that every time a row is selected in the grid, the underlying data object will be populated into the property on the ViewModel.

You then bind your details user control to the same SelectedItem property on the ViewModel. Check this very simple example of a DataGrid and TextBox binding to the same SelectedItem property:

### ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication11
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<Customer> MyList 
        {
            get { return _myList; }
            set
            {
                _myList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
            }
        }

        public Customer SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Customer _selectedItem;
        private List<Customer> _myList;
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:swm="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:swm1="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="289" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="12,12,12,38" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,222,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,222,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication11
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
            vm.MyList = new List<Customer>(new Customer[] { new Customer() { Name = "Bugs Bunny" }, new Customer() { Name = "Elmer Fudd" } });
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this and then select a row in the grid the name of the customer will be populated into the textbox underneath. If you then modify the name in the textbox and remove focus from it (TAB out of it) then the row in the datagrid will get updated with the new name - all through binding.

For further information, there have previously been a [few thousand questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+mvvm) on Stack Overflow regarding the MVVM pattern with WPF, [many of them specifically about master-detail views](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+%5Bmvvm%5D+grid+master+detail) like the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML markup, just bind the edit panel's object to the selected object in the grid object.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to my problem. What of in the case of a pop up form, how would I set my selected object on a DataGrid to the Popup Form SelectObject. I know I could do some ugly code behind to make this work, but I would like to know if there is another way to do this following MVVM principles and practises. Please assist, thank you

Comment: In this particular case, I don't recommend doing it only with data binding.  Data binding is for propagating values, but you are trying to implement an edit functionality here.  Functionalities should be implemented in code.  The MVVM model makes this clear (functionalities reside in the VM).  Data binding is used to bind values from an object to controls in the view.  If you try to get data binding to do something it is not designed to do well, then you'll regret it later.

Comment: Yes I agree, I meant in code, because I have tried implementing this but for some reason my editor panel, i.e. part with my textboxes and combos is not bound. I have resorted to adding these controls onto the same usercontrol as the grid and it works, but I had wanted to make these two components loosely coupled. Thank you for the explanation.